# How to synchronize a bunch of effects in only one thread at a time

Tags: multithreading, scala, functional-programming, scala-cats, cats-effect

i have a small problem.

```scala
      for
        map <- kafkaEventHoldLine.get // Ref[F, List[String]]
        key = dr.derived + dr.metricId.toString
        _ <- if !map.contains(key) then
          for
            _ <- addToHoldLine(key)
            process <- outlierProcessor.process(dr).timed
            (timeProcess, ol) = process
            _ <- info("Outlier.process", timeProcess.toMillis.named("duration"), dr.derived.named("sid"), dr.metricId.toString.named("mid"))
            append <- ol.traverse_(odt.append).timed
            (timeAppend, _) = append
            _ <- info("Outlier.append", timeAppend.toMillis.named("duration"), dr.derived.named("sid"), dr.metricId.toString.named("mid"))
            _ <- counters.processOutlier.observeTime(timeProcess + timeAppend)
            _ <- clearHoldLine(key)
          yield ()
        else
          Async[F].sleep(delayHoldLine.milliseconds) >> outlierProcess(dr)
      yield ()
```

this bunch of code is running concurrent. BUT i want to

```scala
      for
        map <- kafkaEventHoldLine.get // Ref[F, List[String]]
        key = dr.derived + dr.metricId.toString
        _ <- if !map.contains(key) then
          for
            _ <- addToHoldLine(key)
```

be synchronized between threads.

So i'm basically affraid of fetching outdated data from the ref in another thread, and i want to make all threads wait until working thread finishes `addToHoldLine` function, because after executing it, i mutate the state of a ref, making map.contains(key) return `true`

Comment: You want to use [`AtomicCell`](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/docs/std/atomic-cell) instead. Also, you want to _"block"_ `Fibers`, not `Threads`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear from your question whether this really needs to all be on one *Thread* or if it's enough for the code to ensure that only 1 runs at a time.

The tool for limiting concurrent work is `Semaphore`. Construct one in the factory for your class that holds the logic you want to limit, and then use `permit` around the specific work you want to limit.

```
object MyLogic:
  def create: IO[MyLogic] = Semaphore[IO](1).map(new MyLogic(_))

class MyLogic(sem: Semaphore[IO]):
  def doWork =
    sem.permit.surround {
      for
        map <- kafkaEventHoldLine.get
        // ...
    }
```

If you need to guarantee that all work happens on the same *thread* then construct a single-threaded `ExecutionContext` and use `evalOn` to shift the work onto that EC

```
object MyLogic:
  def create: Resource[IO, MyLogic] =
    Resource
      .make(IO(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor))(es => IO(es.shutdown()))
      .map(ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService)
      .map(new MyLogic(_))

class MyLogic(singleThread: ExecutionContext):
  def doWork = {
    for
        map <- kafkaEventHoldLine.get
        //
    yield etc
  }.evalOn(singleThread)
```

Comment: Remember we have `Mutex` as a better single-permit `Semaphore`, and we have `AtomicCell` as a `Ref` + `Mutex` combo.

Comment: Ah I think those are new, I haven't tried them yet